# Converting an Excel file into a dta. (stata) file

Tags: merge, stata, dta

I want to merge one using file (which is an Excel file) onto the masterfile in Stata. Might be easy but I don't know how to save the Excel
file into a dta file so that I am, in turn, able to merge the two data sets in Stata.

I have read about the xls2dta command but I'm not sure if I'm looking in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to convert the file with a special command like `xls2dta`. You just import it to Stata and save it in a temporary file in dta format and then you can merge that temporary file with your dta file.

Here is a reproducible example. All you need to do to run this code is to update the folder path in the `local` in the beginning of the code. You should be able to adapt the code in the "Solution" section to your code.

```
*Set this path to an example folder on your computer
local folder "C:\Users\username\myfolder"

******************************************************************
*Prepare Excel example file
******************************************************************

*Use built in example data
sysuse auto, clear
*Rename all files but ID var make
foreach var of varlist _all {
    if "`var'"!="make" rename `var' `var'_ex
}
*save in excel format
export excel "`folder'/autoexcel.xls", firstrow(variables) replace

******************************************************************
*Solution
******************************************************************

*Use built in example data
sysuse auto, clear

*Load the excelfile into a temporary .dta file
preserve
    import excel "`folder'/autoexcel.xls", firstrow clear
    tempfile autoexcel_tmp
    save `autoexcel_tmp'
restore

*Merge the dta file in memory with tempfile of excel file in dta format
merge 1:1 make using `autoexcel_tmp'
```